# How to completely replace a column's values with NA based on a column prefix?

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a df like `iris`. I want to mutate the columns starting with `Petal` and replace them completely with `NA` values. How can I achieve this in R, ideally using a `dplyr` pipe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)
iris <- iris %>% mutate(across(starts_with('Petal'), ~NA))
```

In base R -

```
iris[startsWith(names(iris), 'Petal')] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep('^Petal', names(iris))
as.data.table(iris)[, (nm1) := NA][]
```